# Helios: ViewPart ToolBar appears Duplicated on RCP View

Tags: eclipse, duplicates, toolbar, rcp, helios

I'm having a problem with Eclipse Helios and ToolbarManager on RCP Views.

In the view class (extends ViewPart), **the toolbar is created as follows**:

```
IToolBarManager toolbarManager = getViewSite().getActionBars().getToolBarManager();  
toolbarManager.add(action1);  
toolbarManager.add(action2);  
toolbarManager.add(...);
```

What happens?

**When the view is opening, the Toolbar is created on the left side** (on the title place) and then on the correct side.

**When the view is opened, the "duplicated" left toolbar disappears!**

**The worst problem is on the Workbench restore side** (and i believe it's related with this behavior): when there is more than one view to restore, a "duplicated" version of the Toolbar of the first view opened is created on the left side of the Workbench itself!!! And it does not go away until i swap to the view under it.

I really need a tip on this one...

NOTE: This never happened with previous versions of Eclipse.

Thanks!

Comment: BUG opened: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336564

Comment: Yes! I will edit the question. It was an Eclipse BUG that is now resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tested with Indigo Release Build id: 20110319-2305. FIXED.

See eclipse BUG: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=336564